# angular-img-cropper failing to set crop size tool on squared crop with square picture

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web, html5-canvas

We are using https://github.com/AllanBishop/angular-img-cropper and so far, its has been great, but today we stumble into a bug, basically, when you load a squared image like this one:

[image]

The cropper tool becomes tiny and almost impossible to use, and if you click the yellow cross, its goes insanely big.

[image]
[image]

We just posted the bug on the dev's git
https://github.com/AllanBishop/angular-img-cropper/issues/93

The bug is easily replicated using devs bin https://github.com/AllanBishop/angular-img-cropper  just go there, modify the html to have this parameters in the canvas crop-width="720" crop-height="720" and load the first iamge on the post image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution was to add a white image for a .5 seconds while the cropper tool gets initialized, then set the image that the user actually selected using a timeout.

```
vm.setCropperImage =  function(imgBase64) {
            var imgPlaceholder = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADcAAAAqCAIAAACY8VRUAAAAA3NCSVQICAjb4U/gAAAASUlEQVRYhe3OsQ3AIBAAsZD9d35WoDgJCnsCr5n5nvffDhyx7Fh2LDuWHcuOZceyY9mx7Fh2LDuWHcuOZceyY9mx7Fh2LDuWnQ30YQNRzV7JZAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg==';  
            vm.cropper.sourceImage = imgPlaceholder;

            $timeout(function() {
                vm.cropper.sourceImage = imgBase64;
                $scope.ngModel = imgBase64;
            }, 50);
        };
```